# counter in switch does not add with jquery

Tags: jquery, each, counter

I have a counter build into a switch with each loop it should count l, u or f.
It loops correct and hits the case, but does not add +1, output after the each is still 0.
I also tried to use "l++" but delivers me the same output.

What do I do wrong within this...

```
var l = 0, d = 0, f = 0;
                        $.each(data[item.source], function (l, li) {
                            switch (parseInt(li.hand_type_id)) {
                                case 453:
                                    {
                                        l = l + 1;
                                        break;
                                    }
                                case 454:
                                    {
                                        d = d + 1;
                                        break;
                                    }
                                case 455:
                                    {
                                        f = f + 1;
                                        break;
                                    }
                                default:
                                    break;
                            }
                        });
var $like = $("<div>", {
                            html: l
                        }).appendTo(object);
                        var $likeImg = $("<img>", {
                            src: "img/like.jpg",
                            width: 20,
                            height: 20
                        }).appendTo($like);
```

Comment: what is `data[item.source]`

Comment: Its JSON array, the each loops thats not the issue, only counter does not counts for some strange reason

Comment: which means that the case statements are not working... so we have to see the data to simulate the issue

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Ls90opzw/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `l` as a function parameter name, so you have effectively hidden your `l` variable.

Change the parameter name to something else that does not clash with one of your variables.

Comment: Oooooh, crap, working to hard I think, thanks for the sharp notice )